# How to give user access to Jenkins single job

Tags: jenkins, permissions

How to allow a user in Jenkins to access only single job?

We use *Jenkins own user database* and *Project based matrix authorization strategy*.

User can login only if I give overall read, once I give *Overall Read* he can build as well not sure why. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried it here at _Configure Global Security_. A user with just _Overall Read_ is just able to see Jenkins' UI but not any job. With _Job Read_ in addition he can see the jobs but not build them. Are you sure that the user doesn't belong to a group from where he/she inherits extra permissions?

Comment: Also check _anonymous_ and _authenticated_ groups permissions.

Comment: sorry, we didnt configure any roles, but added new role (manager user option). then not sure how to configure further to single job access.